# Difference between C global and local _static_ variables?

Tags: c, scope, static, linkage, storage-duration

My C is quite rusty, please help me out.

```
static int i = 42;
int main()
{
}
```

creates a variable `i` with global scope and internal linkage. Meaning anyone can refer to it but only entries within the translation unit(.c file) will not break the linker. It is allocated during program linking and is initialized before `main()` is entered.

```
void foo()
{
    static int i = 69;
}
```

creates a variable with function scope and no linkage. Meaning nothing outside of `foo()` can refer to it and even if the compiler didn't cry out, taking the address of this (essentially protected global) variable is UB. It is allocated during program linking and is initialized when `foo()` is first called.

Please correct me!

Comment: Always use the [tag:c] tag when asking C questions or your question risk disappearing into the void. I only stumbled upon this question by accident just now, 3 weeks late. The kind of people who can answer these questions will follow the [tag:c] tag but perhaps not the [tag:c17]  tag (which has nothing to do with your question). I'll correct the tags now.

Comment: "Meaning anyone can refer to it but only entries within the translation unit(.c file) will not break the linker": no. Meaning it is only visible in the current translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

> creates a variable i with global scope and internal linkage. Meaning anyone can refer to it but only entries within the translation unit(.c file) will not break the linker. It is allocated during program linking and is initialized before main() is entered.

Correct, except the formal term is *file scope* (outside any function), not to mixed up with "global" which can often mean accessible everywhere. In this case the variable is declared at file scope but it is not "globally" accessible. Generally, the informal term "global" is used together with the formal term *external linkage* and usage of the `extern` keyword.

> creates a variable with function scope and no linkage.

No, it creates a variable with *block scope*. There exists a formal term *function scope* but it refers to the scope of `goto` labels. C has four scopes: *file scope*, *function scope*, *block scope* and *function prototype scope*. Those who aren't language lawyers or spaghetti programmers only need to know about file scope and block scope.

> Meaning nothing outside of foo() can refer to it

Correct.

> even if the compiler didn't cry out, taking the address of this (essentially protected global) variable is UB

No, this is wrong. Scope doesn't determine if a variable can be accessed or not, *storage duration* does. Both your examples declare variables with the same *static storage duration* but with different scopes. A variable with static storage duration persists and remains valid throughout the execution of the program.

Therefore it is fine and well-defined to return a pointer to a block scope variable with static storage duration. (It may not be thread-safe however, but that's another story.)

> It is allocated during program linking

Correct.

> and is initialized when foo() is first called.

No, this is wrong. All variables with static storage duration, regardless of their scope, are initialized *before* main() is called. Either to an explicit initializer as in your examples (typically meaning it gets allocated in a segment named `.data`) or to zero in case it wasn't explicitly initialized (all static storage variables set to zero typically gets allocated in a segment named `.bss`).